# Overload template method in template class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to overload a template method in a template class. But it will only work if I do it inside the class definition.

How do I get the external implementation outside of the class definition?

```
template<typename B>
class ClassA {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void foo( T a );

    template<>
    void foo( std::string a ) { A = 4; }

    template<>
    void foo( float a );

    B A;
}; 

template<typename B>
template<typename T>
void ClassA<B>::foo( T a ) { A = a; }

template<typename B>
template<>
void ClassA<B>::foo<float>( float a ) { A = a; } 
// Compiler error: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

void foo() {
    ClassA<int> a;
    a.foo( 1 );
    a.foo<std::string>( "kat" );
    a.foo<float>( 4.5f );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the overloads don't have any template parameters, they aren't templates any more.

```
template<typename B>
class ClassA {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void foo( T a );

    void foo( std::string a ) { A = 4; }

    void foo( float a );

    B A;
};
```

In the version with `template<>`, they are *specializations*, not overloads. Overloading, not specialization, is probably what you want.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't see that. Thaks.